# Can I create and populate a new Google Docs spreadsheet without authenticating the user?

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs, google-docs-api, google-sheets-api

I want to send some data from my site to a new spreadsheet in Google Docs.

For example, I'd like to redirect the user to http://docs.google.com/hypothetical_create_spreadsheet?csv=www.mysite.com/mydata.csv to create a new spreadsheet populated with mydata.csv

Kind of like Twitter's "intents" API.

Is anything like this possible, or do I need to use the authenticated Google Docs APIs?

Comment: "authenticated"? what is an "authenticated" Google Docs API? You can create code to do this with Google-apps-script or the gdata style spreadsheet api. Both would work.

Answer (score 0):

In order to **create** a spreadsheet you need to be authenticated as a user. You can skip authentication only when you want to **read** a spreadsheet that has already been created and has public permissions.